# Mimic.js handle fault response

Tags: response, fault

i use mimic.js regarding a project that i m developing..
the issue that i face, is if there is a fault response from the webservice,
mimic, doesn't handle it, and the browser remains "awaiting" for a response, that has actually been back, but hasn't been handled by mimic..
to be more specific, one typical fault response is the following..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name><value><int>104</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name><value><string>Invalid Input Parameters</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value></fault></methodResponse>
```

and chrome console get me the error

> mimic.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

any suggestions on how to handle "fault" responses?
mimic.js hasn't been altered at all..
also tried to bypass the fact that mimic can't handle the fault, by trying to use the isFault flag, in the if statement, with no success either..
isFault is supposed to get a boolean value, i guess true/false?

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the problem..
when there was an error, the response, from the web service returned with a header as text/html this had as a result mimic.js not to be able to identify that the response was valid xml, and ended with the uncaught typeerror...

only way that i currently figured to handle this, is just with a try..catch, which doesn't actually solves the problem, it just bypass it..and return with a generic alert..